# How to display Dash Home by keyboard shortcut

Tags: shortcut-keys, unity-dash

I wish to press Super (or any other key combination) and start typing to launch programs. How do I do it?
Thanks

Comment: Isn't that the default key?..

Comment: Super Key = Windows Key

Comment: Also, to answer your question. Move your hand over the keyboard, then down near the Windows Key, then put your Index finger on it, press it, and done!. Unless of course you actaully mean another key which then the answer from the user below is what you want.

Comment: Well, this is embarassing :-) Looks like somehow I managed to unset the key in Compiz Config Settings Manager.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Super key is the default key for opening dashboard.

You can find more help from this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/shell-keyboard-shortcuts.html)

or otherwise you can use Compiz Configuration Settings Manager for changing keys

install compizconfig-settings-manager

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

After that open dash and type **ccsm**, then go to **unity plugin** option

[image: unity plugin]

Change key from here.

Comment: BTW the package is now called `compizconfig-settings-manager`

Comment: I fixed the package above, but the screenshot is also out of date. Now, instead of going to `Behavior->Key to show the launcher` you go to `Launcher->Key to show the Dash, Launcher, and Help Overlay`.

Answer (score 4):

super key is the default key for "dash home".
By the way, press super key and hold it, and it will show you all keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 3):

**Super** is the key you press to access **Dash Home**.

```
    The Super key is equivalent to the windows logo key or the ⌘ (command) key. 
In Ubuntu, it's just another name for the windows logo key.
```

You can always change mapping of such keys. In Ubuntu 12.04 you can do so from

```
System Settings -> Keyboard Layout -> options -> Alt/Win key behavior.
```