# Ubuntu search in plank?

Tags: 16.04

When hiding the normal unity launcher, the search button also disappears.

I'm trying to use plank instead now. I'd like to get some sort of search function fixed so I can search for apps on my computer, any ideas?

Comment: On Unity, the hotkey for search is just pressing `ALT`.

Comment: @OwenHines Alt brings up the command input: "type in your command". So it's not the same thing.

Comment: Whoops, sorry. Try your Super key (i.e. `Windows key`, `Mac key`, etc.)

Comment: @OwenHines hehe that would work. Unfortunetly my keyboard has skipped the windows key to the left (haha). So i need to have a shortcut to click on :(

Comment: Hmm, do you have a key that you're willing to re-assign to the `SUPER` key? There's a post that explains the process well [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/98642/how-to-display-dash-home-by-keyboard-shortcut).